# Beckhoff data extraction

Tags: c++, plc, twincat

I have 2 already functional systems, one of them uses Beckhoff and I need to integrate them. I'm very new to Beckhoff, but I saw it's possible to use C++ code and put it to run in its drive.

So what I'd like to ask is: is there some API I could use to get data from the sensors in its unit (a CX9020)?
I was thinking to put a process running in the OS of this unit, so I could send these data to the another device via Ethernet, but I can't use one PC in the middle (which means, no Twincat Graphical interface).

Comment: please post you code it will be useful to recognize your quesiton

Comment: you can access variables inside the plc with TcAds or OPC

Comment: The best choice is to use the MQTT publisher built in the Beckhoff CPU and make the other system to subscribe to the tags